# Windows 7 crashing rebooting when Android App crashes with Java NullPointerException in Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, android-emulator

Windows crashes (reboots all sudden) on nullpointerexception inside Android App in emulator

On reboot windows shows BCcode 3b and minidump etc

Why would App crashes with Java nullpointerexception inside the Android emulator cause the entire PC to crash?

Comment: A quick search shows that the error code is related to drivers. You should check what has been installed/updated recently. I would also recreate the Android emulator if any emulator component got updated.

Comment: I've been down that path. No drivers were updated for long time. Crash only appeared when I went back to Eclipse for some old projects and used its emulator. And only crashes when App crashes inside emulator with NullPointerException. My research indicates something passing bad data to kernel, possibly a BUG with Android Emulator or even related to INTEL CPU "bugs" security vulnerabilities discovered lately. Or who knows maybe bad memory area that's only touched when the crash happens.

Comment: If you are using old emulator image with new emulator SDK, that can cause problems. If you are always using a recently created emulator image, then your assessment sounds reasonable. (Don't know why you are still using Eclipse rather than Android Studio, but that shouldn't be related if you are running recent emulator)

Comment: yea I'm "usually" using android Studio with other projects so just had these crashes with old eclipse project but I thought strange for nullpointer inside emulator to crash entire PC. Maybe i'll go through hassle sometime to go find Windows Symbols files somewhere so I can debug the minidump files. Not sure where can get the Symbols .pdb files I need.